# Second subdomain redirects to the main domain, but URL remains the same as second domain

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

It's quite strange to see this issue as title describes. Here are the details:

1) Created a A-record with "a1". Means subdomain is: `a1.example.com`,

2) created directory by `"sudo mkdir -p /var/www/a1.example.com/html/"`

3) Created server block by `"sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/a1.example.com"`

4) Inside the server block, core parts:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/a1.example.com/html;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name a1.example.com

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```

5) created the link: `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/a1.example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

6) `sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, uncomment: `server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;`

Make sure: `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` is there

7) restarted nginx: `sudo service nginx restart`

**Tricky part: By doing so, the first subdomain, `a1.example.com` works fine. 
But when I tried to create the second subdomain, `b2.example.com` following the exact steps above, `b2.example.com` simply does't work: it will redirect to the main page, but the URL remains as `b2.example.com`**

what can be wrong?

thank you very much!

---

config for `a1.example.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/a1.example.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name a1.example.com;

    rewrite ^/archives/(\d+)$ http://a1.example.com/?p=$1 permanent;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;

    }

}
```

config for `b2.example.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/b2.example.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name b2.example.com;

    rewrite ^/archives/(\d+)$ http://b2.example.com/?p=$1 permanent;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&args;

    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;

    }

}
```

---

a portion of log from access.log

```
[my IP address] - - [04/Feb/2016:00:11:05 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 147 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
[my IP address] - - [04/Feb/2016:00:11:05 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 142 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
[my IP address] - - [04/Feb/2016:00:11:08 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 17176 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
[my IP address] - - [04/Feb/2016:00:11:09 -0500] "GET /wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.4.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://b2.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
[my IP address] - - [04/Feb/2016:00:11:09 -0500] "GET /wp-content/uploads/wp-less/themename/css/main-a800d37d44.css?ver=2.3.3 HTTP/1.1" 301 184 "http://b2.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
```

I did notice "304" and "301", http status. But still have no clue

---

```
curl -I b2.example.com:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.1
Date: Thu, 04 Feb 2016 05:54:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=4r143k0o1m1l62p3g4vt1jrav1; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Link: <http://www.example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <http://www.example.com/>; rel=shortlink

curl -I a1.example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.1
Date: Thu, 04 Feb 2016 05:54:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
Link: <http://a1.example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
```

Comment: did you check error and access logs from nginx? hint: *sudo nano .../..." doesnt create a directory. might be a typo. I assume you meant *mkdir .../...".

Comment: Thanks semm0, yes, it was a typo, should be "sudo mkdir -p" I will modify it now. Anyway, directory created already

Comment: Okay :) what about error and Access logs? Are the permissions / owner of the directories and the files inside correct?

Comment: permission/ownership, what I did is: sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/b2.example.com/html /var/www/a1.example.com/html

Comment: Hi semm0, i updated with the access log info. still trying to find out the issue